# How to delete QPushButtons from inside QtWidgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In PyQt5 I am dynamically adding QPushButtons, is there a way to delete them based on some label value.
I am dynamically adding buttons in the following manner:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.all_saved)):
        

        self.button = QPushButton("X", self)
        self.button.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        self.button.resize(20, 20)
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i: self.future(i)) 

        self.button.move(self.all_rect[i][0], self.all_rect[i][1])
        self.button.show()
```

Once the user clicks the button 'X' it should delete itself, thats basically all I am trying to do here, as to why I cant use QVBoxLayout is because all the buttons would be placed on different x,y co ordinates please let me know if you have any suggestions?

I know we can do this easily with QVBoxLayout or QHBoxLayout but is there a way to do it directly on QtWidgets.QWidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to invoke the `deleteLater()` method that will delete the object and notify(using destroyed signal) the layout that the widget was deleted. Note: Don't use self.button as it is useless.

```
for i in range(0, len(self.all_saved)):
    button = QPushButton("X", self)
    button.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
    button.resize(20, 20)
    button.clicked.connect(button.deleteLater) 
    button.move(self.all_rect[i][0], self.all_rect[i][1])
    button.show()
```

If you want to delete certain buttons based on some condition then you must use the sender () method to get the button and call deleteLater:

```py
button.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)
```

```py
def handle_clicked(self):
    button = self.sender()
    if some_condition:
        button.deleteLater()
```

Comment: so later on , can I select which button I would want to delete, and how would I do that?
I was planning on calling future function to delete the relative buttons, is it possible to do something of that nature ?